# Store output from dictionary to data frame

Tags: python, pandas

```
for k in pref_n_cluster.pred_numb:
    af = AffinityPropagation(preference=k, affinity='precomputed').fit(X)
    labels = af.labels_
    n_clusters = len(np.unique(labels))
    score = silhouette_score(frechet, labels)

    print("Preference: {0}, cluster: {2}, Silhouette score: {1}".format(k,score,n_clusters))
```

Is it possible to save it in a DataFrame? I know, there are a lot of answes and question related to this, but all of them has a variable to which this dictionary belong. But I do not. In my case it works with `print()`

I have tried:

```
place = []
...
place = k,score,n_clusters
```

But it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create list of tuples and pass to `DataFrame` cosntructor:

```
L = []
for k in pref_n_cluster.pred_numb:
    af = AffinityPropagation(preference=k, affinity='precomputed').fit(X)
    labels = af.labels_
    n_clusters = len(np.unique(labels))
    score = silhouette_score(frechet, labels)
    L.append((k,score,n_clusters))

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns = ['k','score','n_clusters'])
```

Another idea is create list of dictionaries:

```
L1 = []
for k in pref_n_cluster.pred_numb:
    af = AffinityPropagation(preference=k, affinity='precomputed').fit(X)
    labels = af.labels_
    n_clusters = len(np.unique(labels))
    score = silhouette_score(frechet, labels)
    L.append({'k':k,'score':score,'n_clusters':n_clusters})

df = pd.DataFrame(L1)
```